# TypeError: dist must be a Distribution instance

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

My package depends on BeautifulSoup. If I install my package in a fresh virtualenv via `python setup.py develop`, I get the following error. If I execute `python setup.py develop` a second time, everything seems to work fine. I have no idea, what's happening. How to fix it to get a reproducable setup?

```
Best match: beautifulsoup4 4.3.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/beautifulsoup4/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b8d157a204d56512a4cc196e53e7d8ee
Processing beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-1eBfi3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2/setup.cfg
Running beautifulsoup4-4.3.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-1eBfi3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2/egg-dist-tmp-YmoFSq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 73, in <module>
    """,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 27, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 129, in install_for_development
    self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 671, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 593, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 809, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1015, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1000, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 50, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 100, in run
    return func()
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 52, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    'raven',
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 970, in run_command
    cmd_obj = self.get_command_obj(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 846, in get_command_obj
    cmd_obj = self.command_obj[command] = klass(self)
  File "/home/domma/VirtualEnvs/orcid/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 69, in __init__
    _Command.__init__(self,dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 59, in __init__
    raise TypeError, "dist must be a Distribution instance"
TypeError: dist must be a Distribution instance
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error has to do with a discrepancy between the versions of `distutils` and `setuptools` installed on your machine.  Upgrading `setuptools` to the current version is likely to resolve the issue.

**EDIT**: This solution no longer works for me (and apparently never worked for Jens -- see comment below).  What now works for me is to import `setuptools` before anything else in whatever script I'm calling that leads to this error.

This error is discussed in many issues on GitHub, in many packages, but I find [this discussion](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/784) to be the most informative.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, setuptools imports the setup function from distutils.core, which is on the system, so this never get's updated...

Comment: @JensTimmerman what is the solution in the end for this?  i continue to encounter this error, and you're right, the solution i proposed doesn't work in general.  i see that you've been involved in issues related to this on GitHub.

Comment: patching distutils to not do this check fixed this for me, see Run2's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I was able to solve it was to follow the https://bugs.python.org/file37554/distutils_accomodate_distribution_ducktypes.patch
So - I removed /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py and /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.pyc ( ran a python setup.py develop - just to make sure it fails and is not using the pyc from somewhere else ) and then recreated /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py - only this time with the changes as shown in the patch. Then when I used python setup.py again - it worked..

Comment: any idea when this patch was incorporated into distutils?  maybe . . . now that it's 2018 . . . i just need to change to some particular version of distutils that doesn't have this bug anymore . . .

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this, it appeared at first glance that it was complaining that `Distribution()` didn't produce a `Distribution` instance, but that was only partly true.

`setuptools` provides its own `Distribution`, and monkeypatches it into `distutils`. That works in most cases, but will fail if you get a reference to `Distribution` before `setuptools` has been imported and done its magic.

The top of the script read:

`from distutils.dist import Distribution`

and then later we were importing and using various parts of `setuptools`.

The solution in my case was to do a late import in the function that uses it so `Distribution` was obtained after `setuptools` was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

install dnspython. pip install dnspython. Or check if u have older version of dnspython and upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Try using pip for installing your package

```
$ pip install -e path/to/your/Project
```

See http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs for more information.