# Unable to use cuda compiled code with pytorch

Tags: python, compilation, pytorch, nms

I would like to calculate the nms using the cuda based code and use it together with torch. Following is my code,

```
this_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(this_file)
extra_objects = ['src/cuda/nms_kernel.cu.o']
extra_objects = [os.path.join(this_file, fname) for fname in extra_objects]

ffi = BuildExtension(
    '_ext.nms',
    headers=headers,
    sources=sources,
    define_macros=defines,
    relative_to=__file__,
    with_cuda=with_cuda,
    extra_objects=extra_objects
)
```

However it throws the following error,

> File "build.py", line 19, in 
> extra_objects=extra_objects   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py",
> line 292, in **init**
> super(BuildExtension, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Userss\anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py",
> line 184, in **init**
> _Command.**init**(self, dist)   File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\envname\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 57, in
> **init**
> raise TypeError("dist must be a Distribution instance") TypeError: dist must be a Distribution instance

what am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21136266/681865

Comment: I have tried upgrading setuptools, installing dnspython already but still I have the same error :(